# How can I treat a sequence value like a generated key?

Tags: java, sql, database, db2

Here is my situation and my constraints:

1. I am using Java 5, JDBC, and DB2 9.5
2. My database table contains a BIGINT value which represents the primary key.  For various reasons that are too complicated to go into here, the way I insert records into the table is by executing an insert against a VIEW; an INSTEAD OF trigger retrieves the NEXT_VAL from a SEQUENCE and performs the INSERT into the target table.
3. I can change the triggers, but I cannot change the underlying table or the general approach of inserting through the view.
4. I want to retrieve the sequence value from JDBC as if it were a generated key.

**Question**:  How can I get access to the value pulled from the SEQUENCE.  Is there some message I can fire within DB2 to float this sequence value back to the JDBC driver?

**Resolution**:
I resorted to retrieving the PREVIOUS_VAL from the sequence in a separate JDBC call.

Comment: Use the `RETURNING INTO` clause: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053868.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the RETURNING INTO clause is PL/SQL syntax which is, I believe, not supported in version 9.5 (afaik, it was introduced in 9.7)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at java.sql.Statement.getGeneratedKeys()?  I wouldn't hold out much hope since you're doing something so unusual but you never know.

Comment: This was the first place I looked.  And no, the jdbc driver is not returning anything, because, well, the database isn't actually generating a key.  

What I am trying to find out is, how does the database get this information back to the jdbc driver when it does generate a key, and how can I recreate/simulate that data flow myself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the FINAL TABLE syntax:

```
select * from final table (insert into yourview values (...) );
```

This will return the data after all triggers have been fired.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this syntax does not appear to work against views with an instead-of trigger.